# Excel VBA. How to convert string "Hello World" to a vector of numbers

Tags: excel, string, vba, double

I am new to VBA and have a fundamental question

I want to convert a string "hello world" to a vector of numbers.

Is there a built in function that can do this?

In Matlab, its as simple as writing `double('hello world')` and then you get a vector with the numbers which I can then manipulate.

Thanks

Comment: Well... what numbers do you expect? Position in the ASCII table? You shoudl explain what this Matlab convertions does

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to convert a string to an array of bytes.

By default a string like "Hello World" is an array of multi-byte-characters, but you can use StrConv to convert them to Ascii bytes:

```
Sub foo()

  Dim str As String
  str = "Hello World"

  Dim aChars() As Byte

  aChars = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)

  For i = LBound(aChars) To UBound(aChars)
    Debug.Print aChars(i)
  Next i

End Sub
```